# Polymer paper menu button

Tags: polymer

I am very new to web development and am attempting to learn to use polymer to create a simple webpage.  I have created a drop down menu populated by the names in a json file similar to the below example. I cannot understand how to display the data associated with the selected menu item. below is the demo code from the polymer project. I understand this question may seem very simple to some of you. Thank you in advance for your patience and any assistance that may be provided.

```
  <paper-menu-button>
    <paper-icon-button icon="menu" noink></paper-icon-button>
    <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
      <core-menu class="menu">
        <template repeat="{{name in food}}">
          <paper-item>{{}}</paper-item>
        </template>
      </core-menu>
    </paper-dropdown>
  </paper-menu-button>
```

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways you can check a menu for user input.

method 1
you can use a EventListener to look for the core-select event. to do that you would give the core-menu a id. i am calling it select. 
that would make the function look like

```
this.$.select.addEventListener('core-select', function () {
  // access the value with this.selected
});
```

method 2 
you could also use the declarative approach also using a EventListener but this time as a attribute `on-core-select="{{selectAction}}"` then the function would look like.

```
 selectAction: function () {
   // value would be this.$.select.selected if using the select id on the core-menu
 }
```

method 3 
you could also use a attribute changed function to get the value when changed. that method would look like.

```
<paper-menu-button>
  <paper-icon-button icon="menu" noink></paper-icon-button>
  <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
    <core-menu class="menu" selected="{{selected}}">
      <template repeat="{{name in food}}">
        <paper-item>{{}}</paper-item>
      </template>
    </core-menu>
  </paper-dropdown>
</paper-menu-button>
```

the change would call a function that would look something like

```
selectedChanged: function () {
  // value would be this.selected
}
```

i also made a plunker showing all 3 in use check console for output when selecting http://plnkr.co/edit/odQwNRLFTzyATodQUNh0?p=preview

edit: all this is assuming you are working inside a custom element. outside a custom element method 1 would still work. method 2 and 3 would require a auto-binding template

Answer (score 0):

I'm very new to Polymer too, but I got tabs working this way (i think it may apply to drop-down too):

In normal web-pages:

```
<body>

<template is="dom-bind" id="app">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="menu-area">
            <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}" on-iron-select="_onTabSelected">
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]">
                    <paper-tab>[[item.name]]</paper-tab>
                </template>
            </paper-tabs>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    app._onTabSelected = function (e) {
        var selectedIndex = e.srcElement.selected;
        var item = this.items[selectedIndex];
        document.location = item.uri;
    };

    app.items = [
        {id: 'HOME', name: 'Home', uri: "home.html"},
        {id: 'PRODUCTS', name: 'Products', uri: "products.html"},
        {id: 'USERS', name: 'Users', uri: "users.html"}
    ];

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

When composing new elements:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tab.html">

<dom-module id="app-header-menu">

    <template>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="menu-area">
                <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}" on-iron-select="_onTabSelected">
                    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]"><paper-tab>[[item.name]]</paper-tab></template>
                </paper-tabs>
            </div>
        </div>

    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "app-header-menu",

            properties: {
                items: {
                    type: Array,
                    notify: false,
                    readOnly: false,
                    value: [
                        {id: 'HOME', name: 'Home', uri: "home.html"},
                        {id: 'PRODUCTS', name: 'Products', uri: "products.html"},
                        {id: 'USERS', name: 'Users', uri: "users.html"}
                    ]
                }
            },

            _onTabSelected: function (e) {
                var selectedIndex = e.srcElement.selected;
                var item = this.items[selectedIndex];
                document.location = item.uri;
            }

        });

    </script>

</dom-module>
```